# Fuction to return how many times name is told exact n in R

Tags: r

Dataset:

```
 [1] Wed sun Sat fri mon sun sun Wed Wed sun sun Wed Sat Sat fri thu thu Wed Wed mon sun thu thu
 [24] Wed fri thu Wed Sat thu sun sun sun sun Sat sun sun Wed tue sun sun Sat fri Wed mon mon sun
```

Need a function which returns how many times days come exactly 1,5,10 times.

Outcome should be tabled like:

```
1 5  10 
0 1  1
```

Thought about yousing tapply and use a new Vector as index like:

```
count<- c(1,10,15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your data:

```
days <- "Wed sun Sat fri mon sun sun Wed Wed sun sun Wed Sat Sat fri thu thu Wed Wed mon sun thu thu Wed fri thu Wed Sat thu sun sun sun sun Sat sun sun Wed tue sun sun Sat fri Wed mon mon sun"
```

you will probably want to convert to lower-case before and split into substrings:

```
days <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(days, " ")))
```

Then you can use `table`:

```
table(days)
days
fri mon sat sun thu tue wed 
  4   4   6  15   6   1  10
```

If you want to know which days occur a certain number of times:

```
t <- as.data.frame.table(table(days))
t$days[t$Freq == 10]
[1] wed
```

Here you are asking which day occurs exactly 10 times.
Or if you want know which days occur exactly 4 times:

```
t$days[t$Freq == 4]
[1] fri mon
```

If you just want to know how many days occur exactly, say, 4 times:

```
length(t$days[t$Freq == 4])
[1] 2
```

If you want to you know how many days occur n times you can define a `for` loop:

```
times <- c()
for(i in 1:15){
  times[i] <- length(t$days[t$Freq == i])
}
times
 [1] 1 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

If you want this info in a nice dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  freq = 1:15
)

for(i in 1:15){
  df$times[i] <- length(t$days[t$Freq == i])
}

df
   freq times
1     1     1
2     2     0
3     3     0
4     4     2
5     5     0
6     6     2
7     7     0
8     8     0
9     9     0
10   10     1
11   11     0
12   12     0
13   13     0
14   14     0
15   15     1
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I don't want to get it to return the count of everyday. I Want to know how many days come for example 4 times. In Your case it would be 2 times for exact number of 4.

Comment: How can i table it for n times? Like m days come exactly n times in this DF.

Comment: Can you clarify that question?

Comment: I want to answer the question how often come days exactly once, twice and three times...n times.

Comment: Last thing is that i want 1 2 3 ...n as names for every row..

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `base R` table function:

```
days <- read.table(text="Wed sun Sat fri mon sun sun Wed Wed sun sun Wed Sat Sat fri thu thu Wed Wed mon sun thu thu Wed fri thu Wed Sat thu sun sun sun sun Sat sun sun Wed tue sun sun Sat fri Wed mon mon sun", sep = " ")

table(t(days))
#fri mon Sat sun thu tue Wed 
#  4   4   6  15   6   1  10
```

To re-aggregate the initial table count:

```
table(table(t(days)))
# 1  4  6 10 15 
# 1  2  2  1  1
```

Comment: I don't want to get it to return the count of everyday. I Want to know how many days come for example 4 times. In Your case it would be 2 times for exact number of 4.